# Efficient way to load a json data to backend periodically

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, azure, serverless

I am new to JS development and I need an idea how I'm going to implement this:
To load a huge amount of data to backend memory periodically, so when the UI needs it, the backend will going to return the data without consuming a lot of time

Let me describe the scenario. I am using a serverless application. And I have to create a function to validate if the user-input exist in json data.I thought I can simply implement this in UI, however in the scenario that I added a thousands of column in the data the process started to slowdown. That's why I came up with the idea of saving the data to backend memory and load it periodically. Why periodically is because the json data can be changed during the process.

I hope anyone can help me out of this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you want to save 1000s of rows in the browsers memory to validate a user input?

Comment: Exactly! I’d like to know atleast an idea to implement that

Comment: if you want to implement a user validation, if should be done on the server side with the db. you can try using a ajax call to validate on the server or the serverless function. Storing user data on the client would be fatal

Answer (score 0):

What you need is actually a cache solution. In case it exists in the cache, you do something in your UI.

In azure you can use Azure Redis Cache, Azure Storage Table Services (which is Key Value Pair too, but with more latency than Redis) and also Azure Cosmos DB (Table API, which is basically the same as Azure Storage Table Services).

Rather than append the content into a string, you'll split the content into multiple keys (think as a dictionary) and finally just check if the key exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution for the said scenario. First Put all your JSON data in MongoDB like this

```js
 db.collection('jsonRules').insertMany([
  { rule: 'rule1' },
  { rule: 'rule2' },
  { rule: 'rule3' }
]);
```

So now that all your rules are stored in MongoDB built a simple API which will get triggered every time user input changes and in the backend, you can check if the user input matches any of the records/rules stored in DB at the backend and if everything is okay you can return a key in the same API indicating user input is okay and handle the UI accordingly.

This is the simple, easy and fast way to address the scenario you described

Hope it helps